# Python Tkinter button's callback not changing global variable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

working on GUI Python at the moment. I've created a button that should change what a label says, however, I can't 'export' the new value of `lbtext` back into the global namespace. How do I do that? Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

lbtext = ""


def llb():
    global lbtext
    lbtext = "Hi"


master = Tk()

top = Canvas(master, name="gui")

but = Button(top, text="This is a button", command=llb)
but1 = Button(top, text='Meaning of life is: ', command=llb)
lb = Label(top, text=lbtext)

objs = [top, but, but1, lb]

for i in objs:
    i.pack()

mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "'export' the new value of lbtext back into the global namespace"?

Comment: So the rest of the program can use the new value. I don't know the correct term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the global namespace works as you intended. The problem is the label updating.

This could only work if you are using a *textvariable* like:

```
v = StringVar()
lb = Label(top, textvariable=v)
```

In your case you have to actively update the label text in the llb callback:

```
lb.config(text=lbtext)
```